# Getting TX hash back but transactions not showing on blockchain?

Tags: go-ethereum, transactions, exchanges

So I upgraded geth yesterday to 1.3.4. I've been trying to send ETH to my Poloniex wallet, and every time I attempt a deposit my terminal returns a TX hash, but this hash never shows up in the block chain and my deposits aren't hitting Poloniex. My ETH wallet balance is exactly the same upon checking.

Has this been happening to anyone else? And can anyone tell me how to make the transactions go through?

Comment: Is your node synced, and have you checked a block explorer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try increasing the gasprice. The default value was lowered with 1.3.4:
https://www.reddit.com/r/ethereum/comments/48arax/homestead_release_faq/
Also, please update again to 1.3.5 as there was an issue with 1.3.4